# Linear Layout width and height cannot be set to match parent

Tags: android, xml

i am developing a med reminder app
I have linear layout with two text fields and cannot set my Layout width and height to match parent it gets adjusting to my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.nsk.medapp.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Add Pills"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Edit Pills"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"gets adjusting to my code"*

Comment: You don't need the constraint layout to achieve that, simply make your LinearLayout your root and you should be good to go

Comment: Just post a snapshot of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Check out your current style/theme for hidden default margins/paddings buried in the different resource files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by ConstraintLayout. If you don't need it just delete and let the LinearLayout be the parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Add Pills"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Edit Pills"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make the outermost layout as `LinearLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout`
- Delete Inner main `LinearLayout` (you don't need it as outer linear layout can do what you want)
- Have weights `LinearLayout` and `TextView` with text view's `height` as `0` and `width` as `match_parent` so they can adjust as per screen

Answer (score 0):

To make full use of layout_weight, set height to 0dp. Also, getting both text views to height match_parent messes things up

```
<TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Add Pills"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Edit Pills"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have mess between constraint layout, and linear layout with weight attributes.
Meantime I made some order, please look if it is what you need. I not - please better explain you needs:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Add Pills"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Edit Pills"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="50sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this, Hope it will work..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Add Pills"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Edit Pills"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```